# Replace spaces with hyphens on submit of WPForm

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress site I have a WPForm submitting to a custom post type. In the notification that goes to the user, I want to generate the link for the post they just submitted, which comes from the title field in the form.

So if they submit a post titled "My Team Is Awesome", the email generates the link as

`<a href="https://example.com/my">https://example.com/my</a> team is awesome.`

So as you can see, my problem is that if their title has more than one word, the blank spaces break the link that is generated. My site's permalink setting is to replace spaces with hyphens for posts, so how would I replace blank spaces in the title field and replace with hyphens as the WPForm is submitted? I've searched this specific to WPForm plugin and not finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code, or specific form structure in your question, so I can't give you a working code example, but as I understand it you're question is actually a combination of two separate questions I will try to answer:

**1. How do I change a WPForm Field on form submission?**

Answer: You can use the `wpforms_process_filter` filter in `functions.php` to customize field values right after the form has been submitted, but before it is saved in the database and emails are sent.

Detailed info here: https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_process_filter/

**2. How to I make a slug-like string out of a text string?**

Use the native WordPress function `sanitize_title()`.

Detailed info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/

Comment: If I had had any code to share, I would have, I just had not found anything to get me started. Thanks for the references. I'll use those and see what I can make happen.